# Common Lisp: Function returns function name

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am currently trying to solve problem 1 from projecteuler.net. Evaluation of this function only returns the name of the function. What am I doing wrong?

```
(defun nSum (n sum) 
(if ( n =  0) ( sum) ) 
(cond (  (mod n 5) =  0) ( nSum ( - n 1) (+ sum n)) (  (mod n 3) =  0) (nSum(- n 1) (+ sum n)) (nSum (- n  1) (+ sum n))  
 )
 )
(setq sum (nSum 100 0))
(write sum)
```

Comment: Use a good editor capable of parenthesis matching. Notice that `=` is not an infix operator in Lisp

Comment: Downvoted because the code is not formatted and thus very difficult to read.

Comment: BTW is there a way a function knows about its own name and prints it in the REPL?

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Given a function object, the third return value of FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION returns the name, but only for debugging purposes. Otherwise, no, you'd have to wrote your own DEFUN variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Errors

> Evaluation of this function only returns the name of the function.

I cannot replicate this, how did you test your code, under which environment?

With SBCL, here is what evaluating the `defun` form prints:

```
; in: DEFUN NSUM
;     (N = 0)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: =
```

The `=` symbol is being used in a position where it is evaluated as a variable. If you want to call the function bound to `=`, that is `(function =)`, which can be written also `#'=`, then you have to write `(= ... ...)`.

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: N
```

Since you wrote `(N = 0)`, i.e. with `N` as the first element of a form under normal evaluation rules, the code tries to call function `N`. In your case, you have no such function defined.

```
;     (COND ((MOD N 5) = 0) (NSUM (- N 1) (+ SUM N)) ((MOD N 3) = 0)
;           (NSUM (- N 1) (+ SUM N)) (NSUM (- N 1) (+ SUM N)))
; --> IF 
; ==>
;   (IF NSUM
;       (PROGN (- N 1) (+ SUM N))
;       (IF (MOD N 3)
;           (PROGN = 0)
;           (IF NSUM
;               (PROGN (- N 1) (+ SUM N))
;               (IF NSUM
;                   (PROGN # #)
;                   NIL))))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: NSUM
```

You are writing cond clauses, and in that context, each clause is supposed to be a list matching `(test . body)`, i.e. a `test` expression followed by the case body (possibly empty). You wrote:

```
(cond (  (mod n 5) =  0) ( nSum ( - n 1) (+ sum n)) ...)
```

In the above, you have two clauses, one which (tries to) tests whether `N` is divisible by 5, and the other which test if `nSum` is true.

```
;     (SUM)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: SUM
```

You added parentheses around `SUM`, which means you want to call function `SUM` (currently undefined). Parentheses matter in Lisp.

### Fixing errors and formatting

Here is your code after fixing the previous errors and formatting it according to Lisp style rules:

```
(defun nSum (n sum) 
  (if (= n 0)
      sum
      (cond
        ((= 0 (mod n 5)) (nSum (- n 1) (+ sum n)))
        ((= 0 (mod n 3)) (nSum (- n 1) (+ sum n)))
        (t (nSum (- n 1) (+ sum n))))))
```

*Your code does not compute the desired function. Please read [Gwang-Jin Kim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50539562/124319) to see how to compute it a tail-recursive way, or below for a loop-based one.*

Some additional remarks w.r.t. style:

- You are not supposed to use *snakeCase* in Lisp, use instead dashes to separate words, known humbly as *lisp-case* (and apparently, also as `kebab-case`).
- Your `if` and `cond` can be merged together. Also, be careful about negative `N`.
- You can do `(or test1 test2)` when both tests lead to the same code being executed. This avoids code duplication.

### Alternative implementation

Use [`LOOP`](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html):

```
(defun euler-1 (n)
  (loop
    for i below n
    when (or (zerop (mod i 3))
             (zerop (mod i 5)))
      sum i))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun nsum (n)
  (labels ((inner-nsum (m sum)     ; using `labels` define local recursive function
             (cond ((= m 0) sum)   
                   ((= (mod m 3) 0) (inner-nsum (- m 1) (+ m sum)))
                   ((= (mod m 5) 0) (inner-nsum (- m 1) (+ m sum)))
                   (t (inner-nsum (- m 1) sum))))) 
    (inner-nsum (- n 1) 0)))       ; call it with n decremented by 1 
                                   ; to implement "below n"
(nsum 10)   ;; 23      ; test successful!
(nsum 1000) ;; 233168
```

Comment: I would suggest avoiding names like `n-1` (but use instead `predn`), since they could confuse a newbie

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll correct it. I removed that `let` clause entirely, so that the naming problem is solved :D ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use [eq](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm#eq) for equality test (or perhaps [equal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm#equal); for integers it is the same), or [=](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) for comparing numbers. And **there is no infix operator in Common Lisp**. So `( n =  0)`  should be something like `(eq n 0)` or `(= n 0)` etc.

Comment: No (= n 0) since he is comparing numbers.

Comment: In CL, characters and numbers that are = are not guaranteed to be equal under identity. The portable way is to use EQL.

Comment: @coredump `(eql 4 4.0)` returns `NIL`. While `(= 4 4.0)` returns `T`. `eq` compares addresses - symbols are stored only once. So `eq` is suitable for symbol-equality. (In some Lisp-implementations, it is said that even `(eq 1 1)` returns NIL. Well, in CLISP and SBCL this is not the case - it returns T.  `eql` ensures type-equality, though they don't have to be stored in the same address. But for numeric comparisons, `=` reflects more the mathematical equality of numbers.  (type of number irrelevant - whether int or double). Always `=` for number-equality!

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim When I said to use EQL, it was in contrast to EQ, not against the use of =. The choice between = and EQL depends heavily on the problem at hand.

Comment: @coredump Ah okay. Do you know a problem where `eql` should be used instead of `=`? Is the performance win really so big that it is worth to do it? Because from Land of Lisp I learned: Always use `=` when comparing numbers. And I agree to that, since people think rather in the mathematical sense when dealing with numbers.

Comment: It is not really a matter of performance, in one case you want an error if some value is not a number, in other cases you are fine with non-numeric values. I agree that `=` makes most sense with mathematical operations.